# Webflux saving to repository without using .block()

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

I have the following method in my service:

```
override fun enableDisable(id: String, active: Boolean) = tryCatch(
            repository.findById(id).let {
                it.map { p -> p.active = active }; repository.save(it)
            },
            DataNotFound("Data not found"))
```

I am having the following error:

```
Need: Product
Found: Mono<Product>
```

If i put:

```
repository.save(it.block()!!)
```

It works, but I read that it is not good practice to use `.block()`. Which alternative can I use here?

Answer (score 2):

Use `flatMap` to chain your functions:

`it.map { product -> product.active = active }.flatMap(repository::save)`